# OrientDB query for nodes connected to origin by multiple ways

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-frames

For example, I have employee managing particular country and particular company. I want to query only accounts which are in countries AND companies managed by the given employee. Ideas? Performance issues to be aware of?

Gremlin query is acceptable, also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
select from Account where 
@rId in 
(select expand(out('managingCountry').in('inCountry')).@rId
from Employee where userId = 3) 
AND 
@rId in 
(select expand(out('managingCompany').in('inCompany')).@rId
from Employee where userId = 3)
```

Remains if someone has the better solution